# Guidelines to understand when to use Apache Camel

Tags: apache-camel

I am slowly getting familiar with Camel, however I am struggling to understand the level of granularity at which it should be considered.  Should Camel be used only if passing messages from one application to another, or it is also appropriate to use Camel to pass messages between components and / or layers within a single application?

For example, I have a requirement to expose a web service that accepts bookings, validates them and writes them to a queue. Would you recommend using camel in this scenario or does it really depend on the level of flexibility I want my solution to allow.

Put another way, if I was required to save the bookings to a database I would never have considered camel and instead just built it as a traditional app that calls a DAL to save the booking. Of course I could use camel-ibatis to insert the data but in this context using camel seems overkill.

Thank you for any pointers on this.

Comment: take a look at http://java.dzone.com/articles/when-use-apache-camel

Answer (score 0):

As you obviously suspect, it's somewhat of a grey line. The more that you need to flexible, the more benefit you'll get from using Camel.

Just this past week, I built a prototype of an app that needed to accept an HTTP post, put the data on a queue, and then pull messages from the queue and use them to update a Mongo database.

Initially, I used Camel, and it worked well. Then, the requirement for the HTTP POST was removed (it became just consuming messages from a queue and updating the database), and the database update became more complex than was easily supported via a simple string-based camel mongo endpoint spec, so I wound up doing away with camel, and rewrote it with just a jms connector and the Mongo api.

So, as usual, it depends. I would say that if you're just moving data between two endpoints, and there are no content-based decisions or routing, then you probably won't benefit from using Camel. Once you actually want to use one or more of the [Enterprise Integration Patterns](http://www.eaipatterns.com/), then Camel will be a benefit.

Answer (score 0):

As camel has lots of component, it looks like it can do every thing. But sometime it could be more straight forward if you can use the third party lib directly and don't have lots of business logic which can leverage the [Enterprise Integration Patterns](http://www.eaipatterns.com/).

The real benefit of Camel is you can focus on how to route your message to meet your business logic needs without caring about implementation detail of the component.

Answer (score 0):

as suggested, there are no hard rules...here is my take

use Camel to simplify technology challenges

- complex message routing algorithms ([EIPs](http://camel.apache.org/enterprise-integration-patterns.html))
- technology integrations ([components](http://camel.apache.org/components.html))

use Camel for these types of requirements

- highly event based processes ([EIPs](http://camel.apache.org/enterprise-integration-patterns.html))
- exposing multiple interfaces to biz logic (http, file, jms, etc)
- complex runtime management needs (lifecycle, policies)

that said...

- don't use for just one simple use case
- don't add unnecessary complexity
- have a quorum of use cases/reasons/justification to use it

along these lines, I presented the following at ApacheCon focused on why/how to use Camel:

http://www.consulting-notes.com/2014/06/apachecon-2014-presentation-apache.html